# How to add bin folder and dlls to gitignore

Tags: .net-core, gitignore

I have the following project structure and would like to add the `bin` folder and its content(`.dll`s) to be ignored in the `.gitignore` file. How is it possible? I have tried many ways like `**/bin/*`, `**/bin/Debug/`, `**/bin/Debug/**`, etc. and none of them worked. Here is my project structure:

```
src
---backend
------Api
---------bin
---------Debug
------Domain
---------bin
---------Debug
------Repository
---------bin
---------Debug
.gitignore
```

Comment: If the the files is already tracked (git add and git commit), .gitignore do not take effect. So ensure they are not in git already.

Comment: if they are already comitted follow this link to solve your issue http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/01/Untrack-files-already-added-to-git-repository-based-on-gitignore/

Comment: This solved the issue. Thanks a million for your comment

Answer (score 0):

The doc (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) says:

> If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular .gitignore file itself. Otherwise the pattern may also match at any level below the .gitignore level.

so a:

```
bin/
```

should be enough

Also look at https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/.gitignore for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding this?

```
    backend/Domain/bin/*
```